# exception in thread, for input string

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, gettext, numberformatexception

I want to get the text from a `JTextField` and turn it into a string in order to multiply the integer with another number when the user clicks on a button.

This is what I have now:

```
firstTextField = new JTextField();
firstTextField.setBounds(40, 200, 100, 40);
firstTextField.setText("Enter amount");
stringTextField = firstTextField.getText();
integerTextField = Integer.parseInt(stringTextField);

if (e.getSource() == secondButton) {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(firstTextField.getText()) +45);
}
```

What did I do wrong?

The error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter amount"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:660)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:778)
at com.company.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:49)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) will be helpful.

Comment: The textfield `stringTextField` value `"Enter amount"` cannot be parsed to a number!

Comment: [Edit] to add a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Because right now your code set a text ("Enter amount") in a JTextField and then retrieves it and try to convert it to an integer, so "Enter amount" is not an integer.

Try to retrieve it AFTER the event you are capturing :)

Comment: I dont get it...(im a complete java beginner)

Answer (score 0):

@jakob :  First of all ,  I would strongly recommend you to go through the basics of java.
Now Please take a look at the examples given below.

Examples:

```
1.String str1 = "helloworld"; // a variable of type String can have only alphabets
2.String str2 = "Hello123";  // can also have alpha-numeric 
3.String str3 = "@hello$123";  // can also have special characters and alpha-numeric as well
4.String str4 = "1234";  // Can have only numbers
5.String str5 = "99"; // Can also have only numbers
```

All the above examples are of type **String**.

If you wanna parse a string to an Integer type you can only do it with the Strings given in Ex : 4 and 5.

The Given **String should only contain Numbers** when **parsing** it to an **Integer,Double,Long or Float**, If not Exception will be thrown.